# PHP extension or configuration to read encoded codes

Tags: php

I have the php encode something like:

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48dHI+CTx0ZD4gICAgPHQxYmw1IHc0ZHRoPS.... ));?>
```

previously it works, but recently when i re install my php to upgrade my php version. This code seems not work again. is there any extension I need to install and enable? Please advise.. I've messed things up =(

Comment: Downgrade your php version.

Comment: @sectus I need to upgrade, because i need to use some other extension such as json.

Comment: You could find implementation of json using pure php.

Comment: @sectus previously I use php 5.1 and I think it is outdated so I install new version 5.3.9. Is there anything I need to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using obfuscated application which not compatible with current version of PHP.

You could

1. install two versions of PHP on your server and run obfuscated application on older version of PHP
2. try to findout implementations of necessary extensions and do not upgrade anything
3. connect with vendor of application and ask for him to upgrade this application
4. [deobfuscate](https://www.google.com/search?q=deobfuscate%20php) this application and fix errors manually

p.s. 5.3.9 is not new version of PHP.

Comment: yep i notice 5.3.9 is not the latest version. But act I need php greater than 5.2 . so install 5.3.